# How to update location.state in react-router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v6.
When using useNavigate like this:

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/", {state: state});
```

I can access it by useLocation().location.state

My question is how to remove this state after i don't need it, for example in useEffect cleanup function.

Answer (score 10):

> My question is how to remove this state after I don't need it

You could read the passed route state into local component state and issue a redirect without state to the current path to clear out the state. This would prevent any back navigations to the page to retain any route state.

Example:

```
const Component = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [state] = useState(location.state || {}); // <-- cache state locally

  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(".", { replace: true }); // <-- redirect to current path w/o state
  }, [navigate]);

  return ( ... );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-update-location-state-in-react-router-v6]

Comment: I've been using `null` instead of any specific path like `"."` which behaves the same way.
`navigate(null, { replace: true, state: { updatedStateGoesHere } })`

Comment: @Jason using null doesn't work in typescript

Comment: That's right, the `navigate` function's [declaration](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/a802be3a05020acdeb59340e96df1335a5122daa/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L145-L151) requires a `to` argument that is of type [`To`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/a802be3a05020acdeb59340e96df1335a5122daa/packages/router/history.ts#L103), which is `string | Partial<Path>`. Passing `null` isn't valid.

Comment: that's odd. I am using Typescript without issue. Out of curiosity, does `undefined` work better for you guys?

Comment: You can simply pass in an empty object: `navigate({}, { replace: true }); `

Comment: @Janci That may work because the `Partial<Path>`  doesn't require any of `pathname`, `search`, or `hash`, but I'd say it'd be better to be more explicit with the object, e.g. `navigate({ pathname: "." }, { replace: true });`.

Answer (score 1):

You should import `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

then make a variable:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

then:

```
<button onClick={() => navigate('/')}><button>
```

And you are done.